# Angular: Reset Form Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I've got a function set up that resets a form on my page. When I hit the "Reset" button, it `.$setPristine()`'s the form and clears the `title`, `address`, `phone` and `links` fields.

```
function resetForm() {
  $scope.entryForm.$setPristine();
  $scope.title = '';
  $scope.address = {};
  $scope.phone = '';
  $scope.links = {};
}
```

The problem is, I've actually got a few different forms on that page, that have different input fields.

Instead of writing several reset functions, I was wondering if there is a way to create a more generic reset function that when run will set the form to `.$setPristine()` and reset all fields?

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to declare `resetDirective` and use it to restore form to it's 
initial state

```
myApp.directive( 'resetDirective', [ '$parse', function ( $parse ) {
    return function( scope, element, attr ) {
        var fn = $parse( attr.resetDirective );
        var masterModel = angular.copy( fn( scope ) );

        // Error check to see if expression returned a model
        if ( !fn.assign ) {
            throw Error( 'Expression is required to be a model: ' + attr.resetDirective );
        }

        element.bind( 'reset', function ( event ) {
            scope.$apply( function () {
                fn.assign( scope, angular.copy( masterModel ) );
                scope.form.$setPristine();
            });

            if ( event.preventDefault ) {
                return event.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpfwe7yh/)

Comment: Would my button look like this?: `<button ng-click="resetForm()">Reset</button>`

Comment: but than he also has to define default values for every field $scope.myModel = { foo: '', bar: '' };